# More efficient decodeAudioData()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I am using the web audio api to decode an n channel audio file into separate channels which are then rendered to a canvas to visually create a frequency meter.

I am using decodeAudioData to decode an array buffer of bytes to then assign to an audio buffer source node in a seperate function.

```
 // load the specified sound
function loadSound(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // When loaded decode the data
    request.onload = function () {

        // decode the data
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
            // when the audio is decoded play the sound
            holdingBuffer = buffer;
            setupSound(buffer);
        }, onError);
    }
    request.send();
}
```

The issue i am having is that when i attempt to decode audio of around 60mb +, the browser will crash due to a lack of memory space.The decodeAudioData function is extremely memory hungry!

I was wondering if anyone had any experience of more efficient ways of decoding larger audio files?

Comment: Are you running on a mobile device? 60 MB (compressed) is big, but not that big for a desktop machine.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is the amount of memory taken up by the *decoded* audio. Just for the sake of example, I'll assume your 60MB audio file is an MP3.

This obviously depends on bitrate, but let's say you're at 128kbps – which is fairly typical. That would mean you're loading something around an hour of stereo audio.

But the Web Audio API decodes to 32-bit and usually 44.1 or 48kHz (this depends on your sound card, from what I remember).

Anyway, let's say 32-bit at 48kHz.

That means each channel is 32 * 48000 bits per second. That's 32 * 48000 * 60 bits per minute, and 32 * 48000 * 60 * 60 bits for the whole hour. And of course we multiply by two, since we're assuming stereo.

That means 11059200000 total bits of audio data – which is a 1.3824GB audio buffer that needs to be loaded into memory. So, basically – that's a ton of memory.

There's really no easy answer here. You could try generating the waveforms/spectrographs/whatever on the server. Or you could try loading the audio file in chunks so that you can process them individually (in serial) and let things be garbage collected.

There might be other solutions, but those are the two that immediately came to mind.

Comment: Or use a MediaElementAudioSource to stream the mp3 through to WebAudio.

Comment: Yeah, if the rendering can happen in realtime that definitely works. For some reason I was thinking OP was looking to generate a waveform, but it sounds like it's actually a spectogram.

Comment: You never need an entire audio file in memory at once, regardless of what you're doing.  That's why the decodeAudioData API is insane.

Comment: I think the Web Audio API was designed more for things like games than playing back huge music files or whatever. We already had the <audio> element for that. For something like sound effects in games, it *absolutely* makes sense to load the entire buffer into memory, because the sound might only be 1 or 2 seconds long. It's not worth the extra effort to stream that from disk.